# How to Locate the Text() center when using expanded(flex:)?

Tags: flutter

Please see my code and scree shot below. I want locate `Text("to be center")` at center horizontally, but comparatively located right side as showen below.

I understand i'ts because I'm using expanded widget and set flex 1 & 4 and `Text("to be center")` are inclueded in latter block.
How can I located totally or relatively center but using expandede & flex property like this case ?

Also I understand I can adjust it by wrapping `Text()` with padding and set `EdgeInsets.only(right:X)` but I can not figure out if it is totally cenerized or not...

```
              Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex:1,
                      child:TextButton(
                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        ),
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          color: MyStyle.textColor,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                                          ),
                      ),
                    Expanded(
                       flex:4,
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        ),
                        child: Text("to be center",style: MyText(myFontSize: 15).style()),
                        )
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Spacer` at the end inside `Row`

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        ),
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.close,
          color: MyStyle.textColor,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 4,
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
        child: Text(
          "to be center",
          style: MyText(myFontSize: 15).style(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    // like this
    const Spacer(),
  ],
),
```

> Learn more about the [Spacer widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs/layout-basics#spacer-widget)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and it was really simple answer for me !

Answer (score 1):

Try below code: refer [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

```
        Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      ),
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.close,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'to be center',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Expanded(child: SizedBox())
                ],
              ),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! and figured out that I should learn lots from the reference you shown.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solutions could be:

1. Use **textAlign** attribute of `Text` widget or
2. Wrap `Text` widget with `Center` widget inside `Expanded` widget or
3. You can even explore the widget `IntrinsicWidth` with `Center` widget.

Comment: Sorry, to be late and thank for your comments !